# I want text view to cover whole Screen

Tags: android, textview

I want my `TextView` to Cover the whole screen in a instance and override all the components in that XML file.  How can I do this?

I have tried by setting `fill_parent` to both `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` but it does not work.

Comment: post your layout xml.

Comment: I see that its a duplicate question. you asked the same question half an hour earlier also. please be patient, sometimes you get late response :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="fill_parent"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have padding set in the parent. match_parent is a little more modern :)